# I am getting a error when trying to set up a local raft network

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum, geth-debugging, raft

When I try to run the command

`geth attach $nodeName/geth.ipc`

It shows the following error

```
'Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -raft'
```

I am not able to understand what went wrong exactly, because I have followed every step          properly and have checked it as well.

need help thank you....

Answer (score 0):

That means you are running the upstream (original Ethereum) `geth` executable, instead of the quorum executable. (Ethereum geth doesn't support raft).

Check your path is set up so that you pick up Quorum `geth` before any ethereum executable. You can check this by running `geth version`. The result of this should contain a line containing the text `Quorum Version`, e.g.:

```
Geth
Version: 1.9.7-stable
Git Commit: 15330fcff698603cab5eb0925c625c6179613245
Git Commit Date: 20200907
Quorum Version: 2.7.0
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [64 63]
Network Id: 1337
Go Version: go1.13.7
Operating System: darwin
```

Comment: thank you, its not showing the quorum version, please can you help how to setup, quorum geth path @SatpalSandhu

Comment: Please follow the instructions in the documents to install quorum here: https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/latest/HowTo/GetStarted/Install/

And ensure that the path to quorum geth is at the start of your `PATH` environment variable.